# adding copy to your application

Tags: java, android, clipboardmanager

i'm trying to add copy ability to my application but when i added it when i click the textview it crashes i think there is some sort of error in my code i added in the `SecondActivity.java`

this is my code

```
package imamalsajadsayings.android.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView two;
    private TextView clipboard;
    private TextView edittext;
    ImageButton next;
    ImageButton previous;
    ImageButton copytext;
    TextView q;
    TextView nm;
    String[] str;
    int i, s;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.second);
       registerForContextMenu(two);

       clipboard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
             ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", ""+edittext.getText().toString());
             clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);    
        };
     }
   );
  }
}
```

the last part is the one i added which allows to copy i hope you can help me to fix it

Answer (score 2):

I think your  variables `clipboard,edittext;`

not initialized anywhere in your code but you are using it in `onClick` method.so it causing you to `NullPointerException` so initilaize and then use it..

Comment: cam u tell me how to initialize them? ,  sorry for the silly question i'm still a beginner